# Universal link always opens app regardless of Apple App Site Associations

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

We've implemented Universal Links as described [here](https://xamarinhelp.com/ios-universal-links/) so that users can confirm their account. We recently introduced some some new controllers/pages to our site and we found that all links will open the app regardless of what is in the apple-app-site-association file. I've checked our configurations and can't find an issue.

Before new pages added:

```
{
   "applinks": {
     "apps": [],
     "details": [
       {
         "appID": "XXXXXXXX.com.mybundle.identifier",
         "paths": ["*"]
       }
     ]
   }
}
```

After new pages added:

```
{
   "applinks": {
     "apps": [],
     "details": [
       {
         "appID": "XXXXXXXX.com.mybundle.identifier",
         "paths": ["NOT /about/*", "NOT /home/*", "*"]
       }
     ]
   }
}
```

**Things to note:**

- I've tried several variations in the paths including "NOT /about*" or "NOT *" and all links will still open the app.
- [AASA Validator](https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/) returns all green.
- I've versioned and uninstalled between each test.

Any thoughts on what we could check next?

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I should have clarified, the second path was just a random test to see if it would still open the app and it did. When I have the path "NOT /events/*" before any path, and a user clicks a link http://servername/events/some-event, the app opens.

Comment: Well, everything looks good in your project while the path does not work. Can you try create a new  apple-app-site-association file instead of changing the old one?

Answer (score 0):

In the last section of [document about allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/enabling_universal_links?language=objc), it says:

> Use wildcards in path strings within the paths array to specify
>   sections of your website. For example, append * to a specific URL,
>   such as /videos/samples/2015/*, to specify all paths below
>   /videos/samples/2015/. Use ? to match any single character, such as
>   /photography/*/samples/201?/mypage. Use a standalone * to specify your
>   entire website.

And

> Identify an area that should not be handled by adding “NOT ”
>   (including a space after the T) to the beginning of the path string.

So, in you second `paths`, you use `NOT` and `*` at the same time which is contradictory. I think you should change it to:

```
 "paths": ["NOT /about/*", "NOT /home/*"]
```

Or something like

```
 "paths": ["NOT /about/*", "NOT /home/*", "/vailddomain/*"]
```

I have not test it but I think it's probably the right solution.